# Widget Testing with Mocktail and Cubits

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I cannot seem to get my widget test to work, and while the documentation does not specifically cover testing with state management, this issue (https://github.com/felangel/mocktail/issues/42) pretty much confirms that what I discerned seems to be correct, however, I keep running into the error

`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<BulkUploadState>'`.

```
class MockBulkUploadCubit extends Mock implements BulkUploadCubit {}

class FakeBulkUploadState extends Fake implements BulkUploadState {}

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  late MockBulkUploadCubit mockCubit;

  setUpAll(() {
    registerFallbackValue<BulkUploadState>(FakeBulkUploadState());
  });

  setUp(() {
    mockCubit = MockBulkUploadCubit();
  });

  testWidgets(
    "BulkSearchInput",
    (tester) async {
      when(() => mockCubit.state).thenReturn(BulkUploadState.initial());

      await tester.pumpWidget(
        BlocProvider<BulkUploadCubit>.value(
          value: mockCubit,
          child: const MaterialApp(home: BulkSearchInput()),
        ),
      );
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byType(TextFormField), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```

Currently pulling the state off `context.select` however when refactoring the widget to use `BlocSelector` I get the same error.

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment:  Did you find a solution? I've also followed the steps suggested on the link you provided and still getting the same problem.

Comment: @JuanDelgado, honestly not sure, not touched this project in almost a year and have since left the company and also moved over to Riverpod.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a brief, not copy+paste, answer for those struggling in 2023 to get this to work:

- When mocking the cubit use `MockCubit`, not `Mock`.
- Create a `Fake` of the initial value of the mocked cubit's state and pass it to `registerFallbackValue(FakeInitialState())` in `setUpAll()`. I'm using `mocktail 0.3.0` and it does not allow setting the type explicitly with `<>` any more.
- Last, when providing whatever value for the state you desire, use `thenAnswer((_) => SomeCubitState())`, not `thenReturn()`.

Hope it helps, sorry have no time to post a fully fledged example right now.